# Event search returns event outside date range

Tags: eventbrite

I have been noticing that sometimes the response to an event search returns an event that is outside of the date range in the que3. Here is an example (with my key removed):

http://www.eventbrite.com/json/event_search?app_key=mykey&keywords=Photography&max=10&latitude=34.19751&longitude=-119.1771&within=50&within_unit=K&date=2012-07-20%202012-07-22

Here are the parameters, one per line:

```
http://www.eventbrite.com/json/event_search
?app_key=mykey
&keywords=Photography
&max=10
&latitude=34.19751
&longitude=-119.1771
&within=50
&within_unit=K
&date=2012-07-20%202012-07-22
```

If I run this query, I get 3 events, one of which looks like this (with some items shortened for brevity):

```
        "event": {
            "box_header_text_color": "005580",
            "link_color": "EE6600",
            "box_background_color": "FFFFFF",
            "timezone": "US/Pacific",
            "box_border_color": "D5D5D3",
            "logo": "http://...",
            "organizer": {
                "url": "http://...,
                "id": 1066754373,
                "name": "Red Brick Gallery"
            },
            "background_color": "FFFFFF",
            "id": 2667310999,
            "category": "seminars,entertainment",
            "box_header_background_color": "EFEFEF",
            "capacity": 8,
            "num_attendee_rows": 9,
            "title": "Copy of Watercolor Workshops with Joe Cibere",
            "start_date": "2011-07-23 14:00:00",
            "status": "Started",
            "description": "...",
            "end_date": "2012-06-16 17:00:00",
            "tags": "...",
            "text_color": "005580",
            "repeat_schedule": "custom-2659333",
            "title_text_color": "", ...
```

I use the keys (under "event") "start_date" and "end_date" to identify the event dates, which spans from 2011-07-23 to 2012-06-16.

The query spans from  2012-07-20 to 2012-07-22.

The date span of the event and the date span of the query don't overlap.

Am I doing something wrong with my query, or is the response incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this event is scheduled to end on '2012-06-16', it is configured to repeat on various dates in the future.  See the "repeats" and "repeat_schedule" attributes for more information.

We recently added support for allowing you to access the array of 'start_date' and 'end_date' pairs (per each repeating instance).

The additional response output should be included any time you add a "display" parameter with a value of "repeat_schedule" to the [event_get](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_get/), [event_search](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/), [user_list_events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_events/), or [organizer_list_events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/organizer_list_events/) API calls.